# LibreOffice calc: How to highlight cell if contain \n in text

Tags: libreoffice-calc

How to perform conditional formatting to highlight cell that contain multiple rows?

`contain "\n"` doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this formula in a separate column '=IF(IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(10),B6),0)>0,1,0)'. Change the 'B6' to the cell you want to test.
That formula checks for the newline character in the cell and if it exists the cell will contain '1'. If there is no newline the cell will contain '0'.
Then you'll have to create your conditional formatting in the cell/column you want to format and make it a 'formula is' with a value of 'AND(C1=1)' no quotes. Change 'C1' to your formula column. Make sure to select your cell range. You can hide your formula column if you don't want to see it but this will do it for you. See the link for an image of the sheet in action. Let me know how you get on. Paul :-)
[Image of conditional formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpmaL.png)

Comment: Ok I test that formula and I go 1 if the cell contain \n and 0 if not. But I can't figure out how to implement this on entire sheet or even better on all sheets of document. As I say I want to highlight/custom color all cells containing /n.

Answer (score 0):

So I'd tried this earlier and I couldn't get it to work but I gave it another go for my own sake, it is the same function as answer below but using only conditional formatting. Create your conditional formatting and use the formula 'IF(IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(10),B1),0)>0,1,0)'. Substituting your own cell for 'B1' and put in your own range/cell in 'cell range' as per image in the attached link and it should work for you.
[Sample of working conditional formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np4XX.png)